# linking and compiling pcl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, openni, point-cloud-library

I have a big trouble about installing point cloud library with vs 2010 and vs 2008, i downloaded latest all in one package for both vs versions, i tried and added all linker(both additionlar dep. and path of these lib files into input part) and also all include files and paths into vcc++ directories...but it always gives some errors to me while compiling.and when i fix them it always increases these errors gradually, all these errors like blabla.lib blabla.h cant be found or something but i did it well, because i have done it similarly in opencv and it just does the trick. any tutorial or help will be appriciated, thanks !!!

Comment: You could consider posting some of the reported errors!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CMake to generate your project files and to use PCL. There is a tutorial on the PCL website which explains, step by step, how to do it!

Take a look [here](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config)!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your graphic card is supported.

And then, go to the official web and download the software [PCL downloads](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/) and follow correctly the instructions. 
At present I have installed PCL (windows) and works correctly. I downloaded the "All in one installer", "cmake-2.8.7" for create the projects ([this is the official web of cMake](http://www.cmake.org)). and be sure to have the latest version of your graphic card drivers. Other possible problem could be you dont have OpenNi installed correctly, but is not a big problem, you can follow this instructions [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDuGfAV6hDc) (read description of the video for instructions). After that, you can run your first sample.

Happy code !

Answer (score 0):

It could be error(s) from dependencies version or C++ compiler version. I had an error from Eigen tool, so I installed suggested Eigen version separately and made Include path to the Eigen folder not from All-In-One Installer (pre-built binary).

This was my setting:

OS: Windows 10, C++ compiler: Cygwin g++ 7.4.0, IDE: Eclipse 4.10.0, PCL version: 1.6.0, Eigen version: 3.0.5 (which I installed separately)